# Animation (bound to scrollTop) only finishes when I stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

My animation event nearly pauses or lets say gets significantly slower at completing when scroll reaches more than 15 percent. Why is that? If should animate to the left but instead it does so only when I stop scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
    var content_height = $(document).height();
    var content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height;

    if(percentage_value > 15)
    {
    TweenMax.to(".bar", 3, {right:"0", ease:Bounce.easeOut})

    }
     else
    {
            TweenMax.to(".bar", 2, {right:"-125%", ease:Power2.easeOut})

    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest including a demo of this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a Demo of the solution with explaining comments:

```js
// This gets called _every time_, you scroll a little bit ("every time" as in "every frame").
// So we introduce a new variable that acts as a filter and only lets the function trigger, once the status changes.
// 0 = not changed (it is, where it was on page loading)
// 1 = out of the screen
// 2 = back in the screen
var status = 0;
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
  var content_height = $(document).height();
  var content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / content_height;
  
  var newStatus = percentage_value > 15 ? 2 : 1;
  if(newStatus == status)
    return;
  switch(newStatus) {
    case 1:
      TweenMax.to(".bar", 2, {right:"-125%", ease:Power2.easeOut});
      break;
    case 2:
      // because this function got called all the time, the animation started all over again, each frame.
      // And becase the animation starts slowly it stayed slow as long as the user scrolled.
      TweenMax.to(".bar", 3, {right:"0", ease:Bounce.easeOut});
      break;
  }
  status = newStatus;
});
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 2000px;
}
.bar {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
  Test<br />
  Test
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way:
Because of the nasty per-frame thing, you can improve your performance *significantly*, if you do not calculate the value of `$(document)`, `$(document).height()` and `$(window)` inside that function. I would suggest, scoping all of this code in a wrap like

```
(function() {
  var jDocument = $(document),
      content_height = jDocument.height(),
      jWindow = $(window),
      status = 0;
  // [CODE HERE, using jWindow instead of $(window)]
})();
```

Which also solves the problem, that `status` would either need a long and complicated name otherwise or would be in danger of getting overwritten by the code of anybody else.

PS: I have to admit, that I don't like your animation in the current state. It bounces too much for me - even that much too much, that I can not see it bouncing at all. To me it seemed like it appeared and disappeared, the first time, I saw it.

Comment: great explanation. It works. May I ask what 2 : 1; does?

Comment: @Daniels Thanks :) Sure. The short answer: It is part of the "inline-if" (`answer = condition ? 'its true' : 'its false'`). But actually it is a [Ternery Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript), which is available in most programming languages such as JavaScript. In this very situation, it checks if `percentage_value > 15` and if true, it saves `2` in `newStatus`, else `1`.

Comment: interesting, im actually learning about that now on codecademy.com.  I tried adding another if statement and adding another variable    newStatusB = percentage_value > 30 ? 2 : 1; which works but the second if seems to revert back when its less that the first newStatus